# quartz.net cron schedule to run job every x days

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

hi what would be the cron schedule string for running the job every x days.

Currently I am trying but not sure if this is correct.
0 0 0/{x} * * ?

where x is the interval in hours. So if i want to run the job every 10 days the value of x will be 10* 24 = 240.
Please suggest if you have better solutions. I prefer the answer be in cron schedule format.

Comment: That is how of day -- is your period a multiple of 24?

Comment: expressing days as hours.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you -- the code you posted will run your program x times a month-- is this what you want?

Comment: Take a look at [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/). If, for example, you wanted to run your job every 5 days at 12:00 you'd use `0 0 12 1/5 * ? *` according to that.

Comment: the cron maker is giving 0 0 0 1/{x} * ? * where x is the number of days.

Comment: @DanielKelley - this is far from standard cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 0 0 1/{x} * ?  where x is the day in calendar with values 1-31.